# How to make a popup activity dragable in android

Tags: android

I have an activity that when ever any text copies in the clipboard (from any other application), my activity coming up in the screen and do something with that copied text (a service is running and listenning the clipboard).so to achieve that , I am using the following code:

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f9b404"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Do" />

</LinearLayout>
```

style :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>

    <style name="AppTheme.CustomTheme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Monifest :

```
 <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme" >
        </activity>
```

and somewhere in MyActivity java code :

```
{
                DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();

                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

                int width = dm.widthPixels;
                int height = dm.heightPixels;

                getWindow().setLayout(width, (int) (height * .275));
                getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            }
```

Ok,every thing is working good , but I want to make this popup window (that is an activity) draggable too (movable in the screen),what I have to do?

Comment: follow this link http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/01/implement-drag-and-drop-movable.html

Comment: thanks,but that one is popup window and mine is an activity that should  be draggable (and a service is running and listenning the clipboard).

Comment: Do you have to stick with the popup being an Activity?

Comment: I dont know how to implement it.if any word copied , I got in service and open my activity like this :Intent activity = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);activity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK;
context.startActivity(activity);